# 0: command not found

Tags: shell-script

```
value1=`$( gunzip -c $Path | grep -i 'https://onlineservices.ubs.com/staticfiles/planning/documents/knowledge-centerWAC.html' | awk -F" " '{print $3}' | sort | uniq | wc -l )`

ERROR:  ./knowledgecenter.sh: line 20: 0: command not found
```

VALUE NOT BEING ASSIGNED TO VALUE1

Comment: Post the complete script. Your error message refers to line 20 but you didn't post 20 lines!

Comment: @Kevdog777 Thank you for fixing formatting and language but when you do so, please make sure that you don't modify the code. Here the problem was in a part of the code that your edit changed.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> value=`$(gunzip … | wc -l)`
> ```

You're using a [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) immediately inside another command substitution. The command `gunzip … | wc -l` prints 0 (which means that grep doesn't find anything), so `$(gunzip … | wc -l)` expands to `0`, and `` `$(gunzip … | wc -l)` `` runs the command `0`.

The fix is obviously to use command substitution, not command substitution of a command substitution.

```
value=$(gunzip … | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the output from `wc -l` is 0 and you have whitespace(s) around `=` in variable (`value1`) declaration.

There must not be any whitespace(s) around `=` while declaring variables:

```
value1="$(...)"
```